# List certain items in a Hashmap, Java

Tags: java, list, search

I'm a newbee to java and I have a question regarding hashmaps (no, it is not homework, I'm trying to learn on my own).
I'm thinking, if you have a large list with names and socialNumbers, you use the socialNumber as key and the names as values. In this case you want to see all the people with a certain name, and display their info. (I have a solution to this, but I find it a bit awkward and I can'tfind a way to implement it to a do-while loop).
I hope you guys can spread some light over this :)

```
import java.util.*;

class Head{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String lname;

    HashMap<String, Person>people= new HashMap<>();

    Person p1 = new Person("Wallace", "Marcellus", "1111");
    Person p2 = new Person("Wallace", "Mia", "2222");
    Person p3 = new Person("Colidge", "Butch", "3333");
    Person p4 = new Person("Vega", "Vincent", "4444");

     people.put(p1.getSoc(), p1);
     people.put(p2.getSoc(), p2);
     people.put(p3.getSoc(), p3);
     people.put(p4.getSoc(), p4);

     System.out.println("Lastname: ");
     lname = scan.next();
//   userinput: Wallace

     for(Person p : people.values()){
         System.out.println(p.toString());
     }
}
}
//Wanted output:
//First Name: Wallace
//Last Name: Marcellus
//Social: 1111

//First Name: Wallace
//Last Name: Mia
//Social: 2222
```

Ofcourse this code fails, I'mjust trying to display my problem.

```
public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lname;
private String soc;

public Person(String firstName, String lname, String soc) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.soc = soc;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}
public String getSoc() {
    return soc;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "First Name: " + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lname + "\nSocial:      " + soc + "\n";
}
}
```

I'm really thankfull for your time and all help. Thank you :)

Comment: You want to lookup the `Person` by name, yet you store it by social. How does that work? Same name? Perhaps you want a `Multimap`?

Comment: Why do you want to use a do-while loop here?

Comment: I was jut trying to see how this particular thing works.I will try it with a do-while loop when i get this part :)

Answer (score 1):

While clunky, it seems your loop just needs to check the names against the input.

```
 for(Person p : people.values()){
     if(lname.equals(p.getLName()){
         System.out.println(p.toString());
     }
 }
```

The equals() method in String is what you are using to compare here.

A do-while loop would have the same contents.

Comment: I have tried this one, but absolutely nothing in return :(

Comment: @JJ72 in that case, the last name you are entering doesn't match.

Comment: Sooo true! I just find what I did wrong. I put FirstName in the place of LastName and vice versa. Thanks a ton. Now it works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for `Person` takes `firstName` then `lastName`. If "Wallace" is a last name you need to write.

```
Person p1 = new Person("Marcellus", "Wallace", "1111");
Person p2 = new Person("Mia", "Wallace", "2222");
Person p3 = new Person("Butch", "Colidge", "3333");
Person p4 = new Person("Vincent", "Vega", "4444");
```

In Java 8 you can do

```
people.values().stream()
      .filter(p -> p.getLastName().equals(lname))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or in older versions you can do

```
for (Person p : people.values()) {
    if (p.getLastName().equals(lname)) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried both, but just gets a blank in return :(

Comment: @JJ72 Are you sure your constructor calls are right? You made the first name is first so you have to be searching for "Mia" not "Wallace" BTW A debugger would show you this

Comment: Exactly! I just realised that too, haha. Thanks :) Would you mind explaining your newer solution?

Comment: Thanks. I changed the names(so stupid). Now it works fine :) But I will have to look into that newer version tho....